# What is the use of following code guard in YUI JavaScript code?

Tags: jquery, yui, javascript, yui3

In the [YUI3 library source code](https://github.com/yui/yui3/blob/master/src/yui/js/yui.js):

```
if (typeof YUI != 'undefined') {
    YUI._YUI = YUI;
}
```

Why does it need to assign itself to a member variable of an existing self (if it already exists)?

**Update: jQuery [2] also use this approach**

```
// Map over jQuery in case of overwrite
_jQuery = window.jQuery,
```

[2] https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js

Comment: It's used in a if statement on [line 436](https://github.com/yui/yui3/blob/master/src/yui/js/yui.js#L436), but I'm not sure why.

Comment: It is one less global variable, according to [this commit](https://github.com/yui/yui3/commit/eb4d2f0e3ecc7405fcd029255385d486212f93d2)

Answer (score 4):

YUI and jQuery do it in different ways but for the same reason: to try to keep things working in case you loaded the library more than once.

jQuery provides `jQuery.noconflict()` which restores the `jQuery` and `$` global variables to their previous value. So you can safely do this:

```
<script src="jquery-1.9.js"></script>
<script>/* use jQuery */</<script>
<script src="jquery-1.8.js"></script>
<script>
(function ($) {
  // up here $ is jQuery 1.8
}(jQuery.noconflict());
// down here $ is jQuery 1.9
</script>
```

YUI does not provide the `noconflict` mechanism but it tries to keep things running anyway. The library keeps some global state in a `YUI.Env` object. If you replaced that object the state of previously loaded components that referenced `YUI.Env` would break, so YUI copies the old `_YUI.Env` into the new `Env` object.